Is there a way to load a palette without hard coding it in Quasar/Vue
I am trying to load a palette with pre-determined colors in an object array.
I am using Quasar's Color Picker:
<q-color
          v-model="storeSettings.colorPalettes[4].value"
          default-view="palette"
          no-footer
          :palette="[storeSettings.colorPalettes[1].value]"
          class="my-picker q-ml-md"/>

the portion where it says :palette, is where you will hard code the hexadecimal colors that you want but I was hoping that there would be another way by using a loop?
I tried v-for within q-color but that just repeat the entire palette, I just want to the colored squares to show up.
This is my array in the stores file:
const colorPalettes = ref([
{
  id: 'id1',
  name: 'Red',
  value: '#E53935'
},
{
  id: 'id2',
  name: 'Pink',
  value: '#D81B60'
},
{
  id: 'id3',
  name: 'Purple',
  value: '#8E24AA'
},
{
  id: 'id4',
  name: 'Deep-purple',
  value: '#5E35B1'
}])

Any ideas?

Can you clarify what is the problem with the current approach and why would v-for be better?

Do you mean you want to loop colorPalettes in a way that the end result is an array of just the desired hex values? Some array functions like map and/or filter is probably what you want, e.g. using map :palette="colorPalettes.map(c => c.value)".

@yoduh, you the man (cue yo-duh)
